# How to add more source directories to SemanticDB in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, cedet

I've read the documentation but I'm confused about this part. I don't want to use EDE projects right now, but I'd like for SemanticDB to feed its database from a different directory as well.

For example:

My project is at **/foo/src**, but I also have some code for one of its libraries at **/bar/src** that I'd like to browse, if necessary.

I've tried using project roots and system include paths without success. How can this be done? Also, how can I know what is already cached in SemanticDB?